# Error in Gradient Descent Calculation

Tags: r, gradient-descent

I tried to write a function to calculate gradient descent for a linear regression model. However the answers I was getting does not match the answers I get using the normal equation method.

My sample data is:

```
df <- data.frame(c(1,5,6),c(3,5,6),c(4,6,8))
```

with c(4,6,8) being the y values.

```
lm_gradient_descent <- function(df,learning_rate, y_col=length(df),scale=TRUE){

n_features <- length(df) #n_features is the number of features in the data set

#using mean normalization to scale features

if(scale==TRUE){

for (i in 1:(n_features)){
  df[,i] <- (df[,i]-mean(df[,i]))/sd(df[,i])
    }
  }
  y_data <- df[,y_col]
  df[,y_col] <- NULL
  par <- rep(1,n_features)
  df <- merge(1,df)
  data_mat <- data.matrix(df)
  #we need a temp_arr to store each iteration of parameter values so that we can do a 
  #simultaneous update
  temp_arr <- rep(0,n_features)
  diff <- 1
  while(diff>0.0000001){
    for (i in 1:(n_features)){
      temp_arr[i] <- par[i]-learning_rate*sum((data_mat%*%par-y_data)*df[,i])/length(y_data)
    }
    diff <- par[1]-temp_arr[1]
    print(diff)
    par <- temp_arr
  }

  return(par)
}
```

Running this function,

```
lm_gradient_descent(df,0.0001,,0)
```

the results I got were

```
c(0.9165891,0.6115482,0.5652970)
```

when I use the normal equation method, I get

```
c(2,1,0).
```

Hope someone can shed some light on where I went wrong in this function.

Comment: Please add the expected and actual results to your question.

Comment: @belwood, thanks for the response, I added the results to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You used the stopping criterion

```
old parameters - new parameters <= 0.0000001
```

First of all I think there's an `abs()` missing if you want to use this criterion (though my ignorance of R may be at fault). 
But even if you use

```
abs(old parameters - new parameters) <= 0.0000001
```

this is not a good stopping criterion: it only tells you that progress has slowed down, not that it's already sufficiently accurate. Try instead simply to iterate for a fixed number of iterations. Unfortunately it's not that easy to give a good, generally applicable stopping criterion for gradient descent here.

Comment: thank you so much for pointing this out! I tried a much smaller error term for the stopping criterion (0.00000000000001) and I got the correct answer. 

Why do you recommend iterating for a fixed number of iterations? How would I be able to choose an appropriate number of iterations so that I know the answer has converged?

Again thanks very much!

Comment: @meri: Just because using a fixed number of iterations gives you an easy screw to turn when something doesn't converge. It's hard to formulate a stopping criterion that will work in every case. You could also print the mean squared error every iteration to give you a better idea of what's going on.

Comment: @meri: Oh and please remember to mark the answer as accepted if it has solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have not implemented a bias term. In a linear model like this, you always want to have an additional additive constant, i.e., your model should be like

```
w_0 + w_1*x_1 + ... + w_n*x_n.
```

Without the `w_0` term, you usually won't get a good fit.

Comment: thanks for the response! If I understand your point correctly, I should have the intercept term in there since I added a column of 1s to my data matrix and used matrix multiplication in my function. With the two independent variables, I should get 3 parameters back.

Comment: @meri: Sorry, I missed that, I don't read R well. Can you provide the output from the `print(diff)` in your question?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a couple of weeks old at this point but I'm going to take a stab at for several reasons, namely

- Relatively new to R so deciphering your code and rewriting it is good practice for me
- Working on a different Gradient Descent problem so this is all fresh to me
- Need the stackflow points and
- As far as I can tell you never got a working answer.

First, regarding your data structures. You start with a dataframe, rename a column, strip out a vector, then strip out a matrix. It would be a lot easier to just start with an `X` matrix (capitalized since its component 'features' are referred to as `x`subscript `i`) and a `y` solution vector.

```
X <- cbind(c(1,5,6),c(3,5,6))
y <- c(4,6,8)
```

We can easily see what the desired solutions are, with and without scaling by fitting a linear fit model. (NOTE We only scale `X`/features and not `y`/solutions)

```
> lm(y~X)

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ X)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)           X1           X2  
         -4           -1            3  

> lm(y~scale(X))

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ scale(X))

Coefficients:
(Intercept)    scale(X)1    scale(X)2  
      6.000       -2.646        4.583
```

With regards to your code, one of the beauties of R is that it can perform matrix multiplication which is significantly faster than using loops.

```
lm_gradient_descent <- function(X, y, learning_rate, scale=TRUE){

  if(scale==TRUE){X <- scale(X)}

  X <- cbind(1, X)

  theta <- rep(0, ncol(X)) #your old temp_arr
  diff <- 1
  old.error <- sum( (X %*% theta - y)^2 ) / (2*length(y))
  while(diff>0.000000001){
    theta <- theta - learning_rate * t(X) %*% (X %*% theta - y) / length(y)
    new.error <- sum( (X %*% theta - y)^2 ) / (2*length(y))
    diff <- abs(old.error - new.error)
    old.error <- new.error
  }
  return(theta)
}
```

And to show it works...

```
> lm_gradient_descent(X, y, .01, 0)
           [,1]
[1,] -3.9360685
[2,] -0.9851775
[3,]  2.9736566
```

vs expected of `(-4, -1, 3)`

For what its worth while I agree with @cfh that I would prefer a loop with a defined number of iterations, I'm actually not sure you need the `abs` function. If `diff < 0` then your function is not converging.

Finally rather than using something like `old.error` and `new.error` I'd suggest using a a vector that records all errors. You can then plot that vector to see how quickly your function converges.